# How to avoid Parent Validation Rule Triggered by Child Record CRUD - RSF

Tags: validation, roll-up-summary

I've got a validation rule on few fields on Account.

I already escaped few roll-up summary fields by using not(ischanged(field__c)), but team just noticed that attaching record will trigger the validation rule, which does make sense.

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to either adjust your validation rules or re-look at your rollup summary fields.  Regardless of the criteria in the roll-up summary field, an edit to a child record forces its parent to rerun triggers, workflow, validation rules.  Take a look at the following document on tips for preventing related validation rules when the parent record is impacted with rollup summaries: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US